# Why is $\frac 13$ rational?

Tags: irrational-numbers

Could we say we know how it is going to behave so it is rational.

But we do not know how $\pi$ is going to behave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By definition, a [rational number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) is a number $q$ that can be written as a fraction in the form $q = a/b$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers and $b \neq 0$.  So, $1/3$ is rational *because* it is exactly what you get when you divide one integer by another.

It turns out that the rational numbers are exactly the numbers whose decimals eventually terminate (as in $0.123$) or repeat (as in $0.12333\overline{3}$).  This is *not* the same as saying that we don't know "how the number will behave".  For example, the number
$$
0.101001000100001000001\dots
$$
is irrational even though there's a clear pattern.

An interesting question, then, is how we know that $\pi$ *isn't* rational.

Comment: Ok. Your second example also looks rational too me. That is troubling.